# Clone a git repository into a existing non-empty directory

Tags: git, branch, git-clone

What is the best practice to clone a Git repository into an existing directory which already includes some other files and folders?

I have created 2 branches `dev` and `master` and locally working on `dev` branch. So I want to clone `master` branch in `www` folder which is the root of a website. Then at regular times I want to merge `dev` branch into `master`.

Now the problem is that I can't delete `www` director because it has essential contents. I also can't rename or move it.

Is there a way to fully clone the `master` branch into the root of`www` directory without renaming or deleting it's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to fully clone the master branch into the root ofwww directory without renaming or deleting it's content?

Clone the repo elsewhere (in `master` branch), then move the checked out files and the `.git` folder to the existing `www/` folder.

You might have to add the existing `www/` files in your `.gitignore`.